# Call to undefined method App\Models\Role::getConnectionName() after upgrading laravel version 10

Tags: laravel

Call to undefined method App\Models\Role::getConnectionName() am facing this error after upgrading laravel version 10. Am using Shanmuga\LaravelEntrust for managing roles and permission.

vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php:794

this is detailed error path.

Comment: Error says ```getConnectionName()``` method is not defined in the App\Models\Role class. Is that defined in the Role Model ?

Comment: I dont have that method in that model, also dont know what that method does .

Comment: To fix this error, you need to make sure that the Role model extends the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model class. You can do this by adding the following line to the Role model class: use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

Comment: But am using use Shanmuga\LaravelEntrust\Middleware\LaravelEntrustRole; this for role management and extending in Role model. If I change this roles and permission will not work correctly.